# Regular expression to parse an URL

Tags: php, regex

I want to use regular expression for url. But my code is not working please help me I am new here.
My url is like:

```
http://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Eagnatec--Opposite-Sun-Vally-International-School-Vaishali-Sector-1/011PXX11-XX11-120601182620-Y5P9_RGVsaGkgQ29tcHV0ZXIgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET - Eagnatec
```

and my code is:

```
 <?php 
   $hh1='http://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Eagnatec--Opposite-Sun-Vally-International-       School-Vaishali-Sector-1/011PXX11-XX11-120601182620-    Y5P9_RGVsaGkgQ29tcHV0ZXIgVHJhaW5pbmcgSW5zdGl0dXRlcw==_BZDET - Eagnatec';


           $date_regex='^(http(?:s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}    (?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-  ]+)*)$';
   if (preg_match($date_regex,$hh1))
  {
    echo "correct";

  } ?>
```

Comment: why are you reinventing the wheel? search for an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, your pattern `$date_regex` is missing [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Then, your pattern simply does not match the subject `$hh1`:

`http(?:s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*` matches `http://www.justdial.com`.

The following `\.` (escaped literal `.`) does not match the subject's next character `/`.